# When creating new android project, getting error "Activity Name must be specified"

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

When I'm trying to create a new Android Application Project in the step as shown below getting error "Activity Name must be specified". Same happens when I try to create a new activity.
I'm a bit confused about Hierarchical parent class.
What is use of it?
Why Eclipse is not allowing me to create activity without specifying it? (It should have been optional)
How can I create an Activity without specifying Hierarchical parent?

Thank You very much.

[image]

Comment: normally you need not specify the hirarchial parent whic IDE are you using and which version

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Indigo Java EE IDE, version :  1.4.2.20120213-0813

Comment: try updating to juno -- i have used indigo earlier but never experienced a similar problem

Comment: Okay. I'll do that. But isn't there any way to remove this error. I was using it before but wasn't getting this error. But suddenly it appears for some unknown reason.

Comment: tried restarting eclipse? and try some other activity names,package name etc

Comment: Yes. I've tried all this. Not helpful.

Comment: probably some problem with the IDE just try installing the new version should help at times eclipse behaves like hell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eclipse Go to Window==>preferences=>Install/update then click uninstall or update =>Click on Installed Software and update your Android development tool.

Comment: @Nitin i faced the same problem four days back and i do the above step.The problem is resolved now.

Comment: It is Android Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819

Comment: But my current ADT version is  20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.If there is no update available then how i able to update.

Comment: @Nitin I am trying a lot but doesn't found any update of ADT. My current ADTversion is: ADT 20.0.3. How can i update this? What steps you take for update ADT?

Answer (score 1):

This is the feature of action bar. I think that the hierarchical parent activity is launched when the user click on the back button of Action Bar. I give the name of launcher activity here and it works fine... As for launcher activity, there is no Hierarchical parent. :)

Comment: For me, it requires parent activity for Launcher activity too.