# Eclipse error: “Activity Name must be specified”

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

Every time when i create a new project eclipse show `“Activity Name must be specified”` error.

[image: screen shot]

After search on this problem i got only these links

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12085398/1250370)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11717294/1250370)

but unfortunately not helping. I am currently using these versions:

- ADT version is: 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819
- Eclipse version is: 1.4.2.20120213-0813

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

**Edit:** I applied all the solution that suggested in these questions but problem still same.

Comment: check  to sure activity name is declare in manifest file.

Comment: This is when i create a new project in eclipse and how can i declare an activity in to manifest before create a project.

Comment: Try to restart your eclipse and pc.

Comment: @SpK doing this several times but this not helping.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the ADT and reinstall again

Comment: After tried this also, are you getting this error??

Comment: Yes nothing change. still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling your ADT plugin. It might be configured incorrectly, hence the problem.

Also check if your eclipse version is compatible with the ADT plugin.

To check compatibility, go here:
https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

For each version of ADT, supported eclipse versions are given. Use the recommended eclipse versions to avoid irritating incompatibility problems like these.

Comment: how can i check this compatibility. please guide me.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me! Let me check is this compatibility issue.

Comment: I tried as you suggested for re installing ADT plugin but this not solve my problem.

Comment: Use an compatible version of eclipse and then install ADT plugin. Your eclipse version might be having problems. Download a recommended version and then install ADT plugin in that.